# API not returning JSON when special characters are included

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to figure this out for the past week but still not luck. I have a problem with API that is crashing or not returning JSON when special characters like letters from other languages are included(Č, Š, Ž,...).

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php require_once '../Connection.php';
 
$result = $conn->query("SELECT r.FromDate, r.ToDate, 
re.Firstname,re.Surname, c.Name FROM Reservations r INNER JOIN 
MainReservants re ON r.Id = re.ReservationsId INNER JOIN 
Classiffications c ON c.Id = r.ClassifficationId");

if($result->num_rows > 0) 

{ 
    $return_arr = array(); 


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) { 

        $row_array['Success'] = '1';
        $row_array['Id'] = $row['Id']; 
        $row_array['Name'] = $row['Name'];
        $row_array['Firstname'] = $row['Firstname'];
        $row_array['Surname'] = $row['Surname'];
        $row_array['FromDate'] = $row['FromDate'];
        $row_array['ToDate'] = $row['ToDate'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array); 

} 
    echo (json_encode($return_arr)); 

}
else 
{
    $return_arr = array(); 

    $row_array['Success'] = '0';

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array); 

    echo (json_encode($return_arr)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: JSON supports 'special' characters just fine, but only if it's UTF-8. If these characters are not encoding correctly, then in some part of your stack something is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **encode** your data in **PHP** api which contains special characters.
And then **decode** it on your client side.

```
//encode.....
$mStrWithSpeacialChars = "Hello Č, Š, Ž";
$mStrWithSpeacialChars = base64_encode($mStrWithSpeacialChars);
```